# How can I get what plugins does the Jenkins that I work with use?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Unfortunately I have no access to the Jenkins installation, I'm just using it.

Comment: Can you change project configuration?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was mistaken. I CAN change the project's configuration.
(But I can't change the configuration of the Jenkins.)

Comment: Some plugins involve personal environment variables. If you can change project's configuration, you can change build steps, so you can test specific variable and try to determine is this variable provided.